# How to prevent queue or disable click events with Move.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue

I've been building [this site](http://dev.jthomas80.com/) which animates the position of several elements, triggered on click.  It works well if let the sequence run, but if you start clicking around quickly as the panels are sliding it quickly goes haywire.

I'm using the Move.js CSS3 animation script to create the animation because I found it resulted in a much smoother effect than jQuery animate but I seem to be having the same queue() build up issues that are common with jQuery.

I tried resolving the issue by adding a class to the body while the animation runs and checking for that class before running any other animation but it has not resolved the issue.

```
$('.bar').mouseenter(function() {
    if (pageinner.hasClass('closed')) {
        page = $(this).attr('data-page');
        href = "<?php echo get_site_url() ?>" + page;
        pageinner.load(href + ' #page');
        return false;
    }
}).mouseleave(function(){
    page = '',href = '';
});

$('#bar1').click(function(){
    if (body.hasClass('wait')) { return; }

    var c;
    if(this===previousTarget) {
        c = -(Math.round(pagewidth / 5));
        body.addClass('wait');
        run();
        History.back();
        pageinner.addClass('closed').children().remove();
        body.removeClass('page').addClass('home');
        body.removeClass('wait');
        previousTarget=null;
        return true;
    } else {
        c = Math.round(pagewidth / 5);
        body.addClass('wait');
        run();
        history.pushState({}, '', $(this).attr("data-page"));
        setTimeout(function(){
            body.removeClass('home').addClass('page');
            pageinner.removeClass('closed').show();
        },1000);
        body.removeClass('wait');
        previousTarget=this;
        return false;
    }
    function run() {
        move('#bar2')
            .ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 3)
            .duration(750)
            .end();
        move('#bar3')
            .ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 2)
            .duration(750)
            .end();
        move('#bar4')
            .ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 1)
            .duration(750)
            .end();
    }
});
```

each element has it's own click event similar to this one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delay the removal of the "wait" class until the animations are complete. The `.end()` function can take a callback function, which will be executed when the animation is complete. You can use that in combination with instances of the jQuery `Deferred` object to execute code when the last animation completes.

You could change your `run()` function to:

```
function run() {
    var deferred1 = $.Deferred(),
        deferred2 = $.Deferred(),
        deferred3 = $.Deferred();

    $.when(deferred1, deferred2, deferred3).done(function() {
        body.removeClass('wait');
    });

    move('#bar2')
        .ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 3)
        .duration(750)
        .end(function() { deferred1.resolve(); });
    move('#bar3')
        .ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 2)
        .duration(750)
        .end(function() { deferred2.resolve(); });
    move('#bar4')
        .ease('in-out').add('margin-left', c * 1)
        .duration(750)
        .end(function() { deferred3.resolve(); });
}
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the recommendation.. I will look into this more but thus far, I implemented your adjustment verbatim and I'm afraid my issue persists.. I can't push to the dev server till Monday so the changes are not live to preview but the issue remains the same.. for example, if you click Column 2, and then quickly click Column 2 again as it's moving, before it has finished then you end up with the page for Column 2 open, but Column 1 showing on the left where Column 2 should be.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I wish I could post a quicktime or screenshare. :/  I'm thoroughly stumped..

Comment: In addition to changing the `run()` function, did you remove the other calls to `body.removeClass('wait');`?

Comment: It took me a few days to get back to this.. but I reviewed it again and it seems to be working much better now.  Thanks!